# Sharepoint 2013 - Hide left Navigation, but not in People and Groups

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

I tried to hide the left Navigation bar and it works without problems. The only problem now is that when I go under: Site settings > User Permissions > People and Groups

It hides me my Groups I created there on the left side. Is there any possibility of hiding the left navigation bar in all sites and leaving "People and Groups" alone?

I made my own css file and used this to hide the Navigation bar:

MyOwnCss.css:

```
#sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
```

Best regards

Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try below css (instead of yours):

```
.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none } /* hide only quick links */
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px } /* make content take full page width */
```

**Explaination:**

Div with id `sideNavBox` is the main container of left navigation box. But it is not the actual container that holds the quick links.

> [image: SP2013 Left Navigation Element Hierarchy]

Actually quick links is contained by another div with class `ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin` which is a child div of div with id `sideNavBox`.

Now people and groups left panel items are not contained in this div with class `ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin` but is instead contained in div above it with class `ms-ql-additionaltopsection` (as shown in above image).

So our solution above hides this actual quicklinks containing child div:

> .ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none } /* hide only quick links */

instead of parent container

> #sideNavBox { display: none } /* hide left navigation box */

*You can find my detailed blog on this matter [here](http://purnil.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/hide-left-navigation-in-sharepoint-but-not-the-group-selector-on-people-and-groups-page/).*

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! Really great problem solution, Purnil!

Comment: .ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none } should also be used to hide the left nav box when suppose you are using the global nav bar on top. Setting #sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none } would hide the top nav bar as well..

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove the sidenavbox only in special cases then you should do the following:
1. Edit the **Relevant** master page in SharePoint designer (in my example below I edited the System Master Page.
Below example checks for form pages and removes the sidenavbox only there.
2. Add the following script (jQuery):
Code:

```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("newifs.aspx") > -1) {
             $('#sideNavBox').css('display', 'none');
             $('#contentBox').css('margin-right', '0px');
           }

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("editifs.aspx") > -1) {
           $('#sideNavBox').css('display', 'none');
           $('#contentBox').css('margin-right', '0px');
         }

       if(window.location.href.indexOf("displayifs.aspx") > -1) {
          $('#sideNavBox').css('display', 'none');
          $('#contentBox').css('margin-right', '0px');
      }

  })
</script>
```

3. Save and check-in the Master Page.
Now, you will not need to edit every page containing a form to add content webparts and such. This will work on all pages specified in the script.